# Alignment of Polygons

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have two polygons on a Canvas. My requirement is that if i drag one polygon over other then i want to find the closest point of both polygons and align the second polygon accordingly.

For example below are two polygons, I am dragging maroon polygon on to blue one.

[image]

So I want to find the nearest corner points and align the maroon polygon accordingly, something like below:

[image]

Thanks,

Abdi